CORS error for stripe payment confirmation after deployment on digital ocean
I developed a MERN app with Stripe payment integration, and everything works fine locally. However, in the deployed version (hosted on DigitalOcean), the Stripe payment redirect isn’t functioning correctly. After a successful payment, it should redirect to the success page, and in case of an error, it should go to the error page. I'll include my Stripe controller below.
The issue I'm facing is a CORS error. I haven’t configured CORS in my Nginx setup because doing so causes my entire app to encounter CORS errors.
My controller:
  const { creditPackageId } = req.body;
  const userId = req.user?._id;
  if (!userId) return res.status(400).json({ error: `User ID is required` });
  const selectedPackage = creditPackages.find(
    (pkg) => pkg.id === creditPackageId,
  );

  if (!selectedPackage) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid credit package' });
  }

  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'eur',
            product_data: {
              name: selectedPackage.name,
              description: `Purchase ${selectedPackage.credits} credits`,
            },
            unit_amount: selectedPackage.price * 100,
          },
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/cancel`,
      metadata: {
        userId: userId.toString(),
        creditPackage: selectedPackage.name,
        credits: selectedPackage.credits.toString(),
        amount: selectedPackage.price.toString(),
      },
    });
    console.log('url====', session.url);

    res.json({ url: session.url });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving checkout session:', error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving checkout session' });
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected error:', error);
      res.status(500).send('An unexpected error occurred');
    }
  }
};

after hitting success URL I am getting CORS error.
Here' my digital ocean's nginx config for reference:
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name something.community;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.community-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.community-0001/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

My cors setup in index.ts file:

const app: Application = express();

const allowedOrigins = [
  'http://localhost:5173',
  'https://fast-track-ib.netlify.app',
  'https://checkout.stripe.com',
];

// const corsOptions: cors.CorsOptions = {
//   origin: allowedOrigins,
//   methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'],
//   credentials: true,
//   allowedHeaders: [
//     'Content-Type',
//     'Authorization',
//     'X-Requested-With',
//     'Accept',
//     'Origin',
//   ],
// };

const corsOptions: cors.CorsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    console.log('CORS Origin:', origin);
    if (!origin || allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Content-Type',
    'Authorization',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'Accept',
    'Origin',
  ],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

How Can I solve this issue?
Also as a beginner can anybody suggest me a resource where I can learn about deployment on digital ocean?

What exact CORS error are you getting? And when? i..e when you try to redirect to the session.url of the Stripe CheckoutSession from your site, or when Checkout tries to redirect to your site after the payment?

How are you making the redirect to the Checkout Url on your frontend ? You should use a server side redirection, something like res.redirect(303, session.url);
You can follow this guide for more details:
https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/quickstart

@karllekko When checkout is trying to redirect to my site after payment.

what exact error? what do the logs you added in that origin function tell you about what origin is trying to hit the server when an error happens?

error message from chrome
" Ensure CORS response header values are valid
A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request.
To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid header values. ..... . "

In my response header I do not see any origin I got something like this in response header:
cache-control: public,max-age=0,must-revalidate
cache-status: "Netlify Edge"; hit
date: Tue, 01 Oct 2024 12:31:31 GMT
etag: "7ad355cba2edjhgy23962d276tg6g52ca3d-ssl"
server: Netlify
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-nf-request-id: 01J943350XANV9FGHTTS2EZPWM507

@os4m37 Stripe sessions return a URL (session.url) for the client to visit, not for server-side redirection. if I do res.redirect it throws error.

What error does it throw when you do server-side redirection ?
